# TAR returns 1 on big directories - how to ignore this?

Tags: pipe, backup, tar, exit-status

I'm running the following sequence for backup purposes:

```
$> set -o pipefail
$> tar -c /vary/large/folder1 /very/large/folder2 | xz ... | gpg ... | aws ...
$> echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]} ${PIPESTATUS[2]} ${PIPESTATUS[3]}"
1 0 0 0
```

When I run `tar` on smaller directories, the return value is always `0`. But when I try to backup larger folders (`+10G`), the return value is always `1`. The manpage of `tar` states:

> RETURN VALUE 1      Some  files differ.  If tar was invoked with the --compare (--diff, -d) command line option, this means that some files in the archive differ from their disk counterparts.  If tar was given one of the --create, --append or --update options, this exit code means that some files were changed while being archived and so the resulting archive does not contain the exact copy  of  the  file set.

What can I do to prevent `tar` returning `1` which spoils the sequence of my backup script? I want/need to ignore files that have changed during the backup, so how can I ignore files that differ? Is there any "best way" to handle huge directories with `tar` - how would you solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to ignore changes? If a file is being modified while tar is archiving it, what's in the archive may be unusable. It's ok if all the files are modified atomically. To get a coherent backup, back up from a snapshot (which some filesystems offer, or LVM).

Comment: If you're positive it's ok to just ignore the issue, then can't you, well, simply ignore the exit status if it's 1 (and not 2, which GNU tar would give e.g. for an unreadable file or other "fatal" error)?